# Bootstrap Navigation Bar Button [Rails]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, button, navbar

I just created a navigation bar for my website and eventhough it looks just as I want it to, my button doesn't work.

```
<div class = "navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
    <div class = "container">   
        <a class = "navbar-brand">#</a>
            <button class = "navbar-toggle" data-toggle = "collapse" data target = "#navHeaderCollapse">
                <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
                <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
                <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
                <div class = "collapse navbar-collapse" id="navHeaderCollapse">
                    <ul class = "nav navbar-nav pull-right">
                        <li><%= link_to "Home", root_path %></li>
                        <li><%= link_to "About", about_path %></li>
                        <li><%= link_to "Social Media", social_path %></li>
                        <li><%= link_to "Contact Us", contact_path %></li>

                    </ul>
                </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is how the bar looks in full resolution.
[image: nav]

and this is how it looks when I make the window smaller.
[image: nav]

It looks exactly as I want it to look. However, when I click on the button, nothing happens. It's supposed to roll down the whole list of links. Any ideas? If you don't find any flaws, could I possibly have messed up settings, which make it impossible for the code to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what's with those spaces

i.e:

```
<a class = "navbar-brand">#</a>
```

should be

```
<a class="navbar-brand">#</a>
```

and I believe you made a typo:

```
data target = "#navHeaderCollapse"
```

should be

```
data-target="#navHeaderCollapse"
```